# Imagecropper plugin is saving image in cache folder. how to save in gallery folder?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile

I am using an image cropper plugin, to capture a picture & crop it. Then I am using Xamarin.MediaGallery plugin to save that photo inside gallery folder in the phone

ImageCropping.Form ref: https://github.com/stormlion227/ImageCropper.Forms
Xamarin.GalleryImage ref: https://github.com/dimonovdd/Xamarin.MediaGallery

**Error:** `**System.ArgumentException:** 'filePath'`

**on line** `MediaGallery.SaveAsync(MediaFileType.Image, FullPath.ToString());`

it works good but the only issue is that by default, it's saving images in the `cache` folder. when i try to use 2nd plugi to save in gallery folder than I get an error

```
            //Use ImageCropping.Form to take a photo & Crop
            new ImageCropper()
            {
                PageTitle = "Crop Photo",
                AspectRatioX = 5, 
                CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle,
                SelectSourceTitle = "Select source", 
                TakePhotoTitle = "Take Photo",        
                PhotoLibraryTitle = "Photo Library", 
                Success = (imageFile) =>
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        //Step#0: ImageCropping.Form, by defaults, saves the image to the following path & gives it a random name:
                        // /data/user/0/com.companyname.appname/cache/cropped296.png
                        
                        //Step#1: Get image full path from step#0
                        var FullPath = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);

                        //Step#2: Save in Gallery folder
                        MediaGallery.SaveAsync(MediaFileType.Image, FullPath.ToString());
                    });
                }
            }.Show(this);
```

***Update:***

**android - MainAcivity.cs**

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

             NativeMedia.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            CrossFingerprint.SetCurrentActivityResolver(() => Platform.CurrentActivity);
            Stormlion.ImageCropper.Droid.Platform.Init();
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent intent)
        {
            if (NativeMedia.Platform.CheckCanProcessResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent))
                NativeMedia.Platform.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

            Stormlion.ImageCropper.Droid.Platform.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
            
    }
```

Comment: Do you have permission to store files in the phone?

Comment: yup, its def saving photo inside cache folder, just not gallery folder

Comment: Hmm, have you debugged it and looked at what path it's using for FullPath?

Comment: FullPath is `/data/user/0/com.companyname.appname/cache/cropped296.png` to me  its all correct but clearly im wrong some where

Comment: I'm a bit sleepy so I'm hoping I am reading the code right. The image that is being displayed to the client is actually an image that is now on their hard drive via cache. When you are doing ImageSouce.FromFile(imageFille) you are actually just getting the path of that locally copied image, which is their cache... And you're storing it right back in the same place.

Comment: yup thats correct. in `Step#0`, its automatedly storing cropped image to cache folder. In `Step#1`, I am getting image path from cache folder. `Step#2`, here, i just want to re-save same image inside gallery folder too

Comment: btw i updated my post, do you think issue might be in OnActivityResult method?

Comment: have you looked at the source of the plugin to see what causes that exception?

Answer (score 0):

working now, I replaced this:

```
var FullPath = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
```

with:

```
 var FullPath = imageFile;
```

i didnt noticed, `Image source` was returning image path with some extra text at begining. for ex:
`File: /data/user/0/com.companyname.appname/cache/cropped296.png`

however `imageFile` returns just path `/data/user/0/com.companyname.appname/cache/cropped296.png`